# Why am I getting "page not found" error in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I am new in Django Framework having no previous experience with any other framework. After writing these code and hitting the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyApp/f2/400` I get the error "Page not found "

main **urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include,url


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('MyApp', include('MyApp.urls')),
]
```

**MyApp.urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from MyApp import views


urlpatterns = [
    url('test', views.Index, name='Index'),
    url('f2/<int:guess>', views.F.as_view()),
]
```

I have attached the image of erroneous page.[image]

**Edit**:
But if I do the reverse work ie I place `f2/<int:guess>` this path to Project's urls.py file and link to MyApp.urls and place '' in MyApp.urls then it works without causing any error (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/f2/400`) . Why is this happening?

**Here is the next experimental configuration:**
Url I used for this configuration: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/f2/400`

**Project's urls.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include,url


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('f2/<int:guess>', include('MyApp.urls')),
]
```

**MyApp's urls.py file:**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from MyApp import views


urlpatterns = [
    url('test', views.Index, name='Index'),
    url('', views.F.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Please decide whether you use urls with trailing `/` or without and modify your config accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `path('MyApp', include('MyApp.urls')),` by `path('MyApp/', include('MyApp.urls')),`

Comment: Also try replacing url in MyApp's urls.py file by path: url('f2/<int:guess>', views.F.as_view()), by path('f2/<int:guess>', views.F.as_view()),

Comment: Tried it too.. Same result

Comment: If you can share more of your Django code, I can probably help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention which file or which portion you want to be shared.